# Golang unmarshaling array gives runtime error: index out of range

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am new to golang, and still learning things, but I have stumbled on this issue.I have json data that I am getting from this [api](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=R8796464&format=geojson&polygon_geojson=1). The relevant parts of json look like this:

```
{
   "features": [
     {
       "properties": {
         "display_name": "name", 
         "address": {"county": "County", "country":"country", "country_code":"cc"}
       },
       "bbox": [13.9171885,44.2603464,15.2326512,45.6729436],
       "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
               [
                 [
                   [14.4899021,41.4867039],
                   [14.5899021,41.5867039]
                 ]
               ],
               [
                 [
                   [15.4899021,41.4867039],
                   [15.5899021,41.5867039]
                 ]
               ],
            ]
        }
     }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to unmarshal it with this kind of struct:

```
// Feature struct
type Feature struct {
    Properties struct {
        Name    string `json:"display_name"`
        Address struct {
            Country string `json:"country"`
            Code    string `json:"country_code"`
        } `json:"address"`
    } `json:"properties"`
    Bbox []float64 `json:"bbox"`
    Geo  struct {
        Coordinates [][][][]float64 `json:"coordinates"`
    } `json:"geometry"`
}

// GeoJSONEntry struct
type GeoJSONEntry struct {
    Features []Feature `json:"features"`
}
```

I am calling the api with this function:

```
func (server *Server) ImportRegionsMultiPolygon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var locations []LocationMulti
    var errors []error

    for _, county := range multiPolygons {
        res, err := http.Get(baseURL + "?osm_ids=" + county.Type + county.OsmID + "&format=json&polygon_geojson=1")
        if err != nil {
            errors = append(errors, err)
        }

        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

        if err != nil {
            errors = append(errors, err)
        }

        location, err := ParseGeoJSON(bytes)

        if err != nil {
            errors = append(errors, err)
        } else {
            locations = append(locations, location)
        }
    }

    if errors != nil {
        http.Error(w, errors[0].Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    } else {
        file, _ := json.MarshalIndent(locations, "", " ")
        if err := ioutil.WriteFile("./static/regions/geodata-multi.json", file, 0644); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error writing file", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        } else {
            responses.JSON(w, http.StatusCreated, locations)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `LocationMulti` looks like this:

```
// LocationMulti struct
type LocationMulti struct {
    Name        string
    Lat         string
    Lng         string
    Country     string
    CountryCode string
    Coordinates [][][][]float64
}
```

Function `ParseGeoJSON` looks like this:

```
func ParseGeoJSON(bytes []byte) (LocationMulti, error) {
    var entry GeoJSONEntry
    var err error

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &entry); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing json", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", &entry)

    location := LocationMulti{
        Name:        entry.Features[0].Properties.Name,
        Lat:         fmt.Sprintf("%f", (entry.Features[0].Bbox[1]+entry.Features[0].Bbox[3])/2),
        Lng:         fmt.Sprintf("%f", (entry.Features[0].Bbox[0]+entry.Features[0].Bbox[2])/2),
        Country:     entry.Features[0].Properties.Address.Country,
        CountryCode: entry.Features[0].Properties.Address.Code,
        Coordinates: entry.Features[0].Geo.Coordinates,
    }

    return location, err
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error parsing json json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type controllers.Entry
2020/04/28 17:36:39 http: panic serving [::1]:61457: runtime error: index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong, how should I unmarshal this kind of json?

Comment: If you remove the `,` at the end of the second line of coordinates, it will work. see: https://play.golang.org/p/w1Ba1vjnCHC

Comment: that was just a typo in the question, the real data is correct and I still get the same error, I will edit my question with the real data api

Comment: index out of range is caused by code that you haven't included, you seem to be trying to index into a slice after json unmarshaling failed with a clear error that you haven't yet addressed.

Comment: since the error says "cannot unmarshal json array into Entry" the actual json, not the one you're showing here, has probably array brackets at the root, i.e. `[ {"features": ....} ]`

Comment: Can you show the code that retrieves the `bytes`, the http request created and sent to the api and the part that reads the response's body into a byte slice? Can you show that that part of the code results in a json object and not a json array in the `bytes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmarshal method itself is called correctly, the problem is that you are requesting [JSON](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Output/#json) format which is an array instead of expected [GeoJSON](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Output/#geojson). Solution for the error returned by `json.Unmarshal` is replacing

```
    res, err := http.Get(baseURL + "?osm_ids=" + county.Type + county.OsmID + "&format=json&polygon_geojson=1")
```

with

```
    res, err := http.Get(baseURL + "?osm_ids=" + county.Type + county.OsmID + "&format=geojson&polygon_geojson=1")
```

EDIT: Though additionally I would rewrite `ParseGeoJSON` to avoid panics:

```
func ParseGeoJSON(bytes []byte) (LocationMulti, error) {
    var entry Entry
    var err error

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &entry); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing json", err)
        return LocationMulti{}, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", &entry)

    if len(entry.Features) == 0 {
        return LocationMulti{}, fmt.Errorf("parsed entry has no features")
    }

    feature := entry.Features[0]
    if len(feature.Bbox) < 4 {
        return LocationMulti{}, fmt.Errorf("bbox of parsed entry has too few points")
    }

    location := LocationMulti{
        Name:        feature.Properties.Name,
        Lat:         fmt.Sprintf("%f", (feature.Bbox[1]+feature.Bbox[3])/2),
        Lng:         fmt.Sprintf("%f", (feature.Bbox[0]+feature.Bbox[2])/2),
        Country:     feature.Properties.Address.Country,
        CountryCode: feature.Properties.Address.Code,
        Coordinates: feature.Geo.Coordinates,
    }

    return location, err
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by @mkopriva, the issue is likely in retrieving `bytes`. The following produces the expected output:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Feature struct {
    Properties struct {
        Name    string `json:"display_name"`
        Address struct {
            Country string `json:"country"`
            Code    string `json:"country_code"`
        } `json:"address"`
    } `json:"properties"`
    Bbox []float64 `json:"bbox"`
    Geo  struct {
        Coordinates [][][]float64 `json:"coordinates"`
    } `json:"geometry"`
}

type Entry struct {
    Features []Feature `json:"features"`
}

var data = `{
   "features": [
     {
       "properties": {
         "display_name": "name",
         "address": {"county": "County", "country":"country", "country_code":"cc"}
       },
       "bbox": [13.9171885,44.2603464,15.2326512,45.6729436],
       "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
             [
               [14.4899021,41.4867039],
               [14.5899021,41.5867039]
             ]
          ]
        }
     }
   ]
}`

func main() {
    var entry Entry

    bytes := []byte(data)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &entry); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing json", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", entry)
}
```

And the result:

```
{[{{name {country cc}} [13.9171885 44.2603464 15.2326512 45.6729436] {[[[14.4899021 41.4867039] [14.5899021 41.5867039]]]}}]}
```